# Gem for oAuth2 Consumer AND Provider functionality in Rails 2.3.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, oauth, oauth-2.0, oauth-provider

I'm struggling finding a usable gem which provides the following for a Rails 2.3.5 application:

- we want to protect out API with oAuth 2; therefore a Controller for creating access/request Tokens and the models (Client, Token,...) are required
- we want to consume oAuth2 Services like Facebook and Twitter

It would also be nice to have support for 3 legged and 2 legged authentication.

I found those gems, but they all have major drawbacks:

- oauth-ruby (github.com/oauth/oauth-ruby)

  - i'm not quite sure if it already implements oauth2 mechanisms
  - more like a basic lib for services on top

---

- oauth-plugin (github.com/pelle/oauth-plugin)

  - looks convenient BUT oauth2 only supported in rails3 branch :(

---

- oauth2 (github.com/intridea/oauth2)

  - only for oAuth2 Consumers / no Provider Functionality

---

- oauth2-ruby (github.com/aflatter/oauth2-ruby/tree/)

  - last Commit: 16.07.10 "DESCTRUCTIVE COMMIT" :(
  - based on oAuth2 Draft 00 (old!)

---

- oauth2-provider (github.com/ThoughtWorksStudios/oauth2_provider)

  - last Commit: 21.10.10 - good
  - only Provider functionality :(
  - based on oAuth2 Draft 09 (quite recent)

---

Did anybody achieve those requirenments with one or a combination of those gems? Could you please provide me a direction?

**Any help is much appreciated!**

Comment: I received a response from pelle, the author of the oauth-plugin, today. I asked him if oauth2 Support would be available in the master branch, too (not just the rails3 branch). He said "It should work well within Rails 2.3.x but I would like to hear feedback about it. I should really rename the branch." ! I'll try it out ! http://github.com/pelle/oauth-plugin/issues#issue/19

Comment: We implemented a custom fork of the rails3 Branch from the oauth-plugin and it worked like a charm

Comment: i still have an issue on before_filter :login_or_oauth_required and oauthenticate callbacks, how did you manage it?

Comment: @gozali which exact problems do you have? we are only using oauthenticate btw (no more login_or_oauth_required); when the option "interactive" is set to true, it will act like login_or_oauth_required

Comment: @makibo : i already solved it by upgrading my gems to the new one, but still confusing how to use the gem properly due to lack of documentations and example

Comment: @gozali you'll need: (1) to create an OAuth Controller:

require 'oauth/controllers/provider_controller'

class Oauth::OauthController < ApplicationController
  include OAuth::Controllers::ProviderController
end

(2) Create a client_application with the generated views or console.

Then you'll be able to fetch tokens like described in http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-08 (or newer).

(3) Where you need to protect access, insert this like a before_filter:
oauthenticate :strategies => [:token] # OAuth2 .
Then you've got access to current_token and current_client_application.

Comment: @gozali small addition: the token, once obtained, must be appended to each request to protected endpoints as extra query parameter like so: example.com/oauth_protected_resource?access_token=VALID_ACCESS_TOKEN

Answer (score 1):

I can't help with your search.  But I'll just say that that's a pretty large number of implementations for a protocol that is still in very active development :)

See my pointers to the current OAuth 2.0 status, as of draft 11, at https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1187/what-were-the-specific-security-flaws-with-oauth-1-0-how-are-they-being-addresse/1201#1201

(Can anyone characterize the degree of interoperability between the different drafts of 2.0?)

Answer (score 1):

Wanted to add a couple more libraries that I've come across. I haven't used either, but I thought they should be on this post for people to compare:

- https://github.com/songkick/oauth2-provider
- https://github.com/flowtown/rack-oauth2-server

Answer (score 1):

I've evaluated most of the gems listed in this thread, and in my (biased) opinion the devise_oauth2_providable gem is the best oauth2 provider backend for a rails app.  it's goal is to be the easiest integration for existing rails apps and I'd recommend giving it a look over.

https://github.com/socialcast/devise_oauth2_providable

You can mix and match a different gem for oauth2 consumers since they are different enough responsibilities.